# React Typescript page - window.print is printing unexpected

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react typescript page.  It's basically composed of a title and some elements on top, an inner page, and then a side panel with buttons.  I was tasked with adding a "print page" to the side panel which should print some third component and open up a print dialogue for it (the window.print for the inner page).

I have 2 problems so far:

1. when rendering this on the  print button, the entire print doesn't work at all (nothing happens).  I was able to solve this by setting the onprint to happen on page load.  Then it opens the print dialogue on page load but still doesn't work on the print button.
2. the window.print is printing the entire context of all elements on the page, instead of just new component i'm trying for.

here is part of the code:

```
const printCoversheet = () => {
    setCoversheetData({
      documentId: document.id,
      somedata: somedata?.data ?? '',,
    });
    console.log(coversheetData);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    !isEmpty(coversheetData) && window.print();
    window.onafterprint = () => setCoversheetData({} as VerificationErrorCoversheetProps);
  }, [coversheetData, setCoversheetData]);


     <div css={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-start', marginTop: 16 }}>
              <Button
                variant="outlined"
                size="large"
                color="secondary"
                onClick={() => printCoversheet()}
              >
                Print Coversheet
              </Button>
            </div>
            {!isEmpty(coversheetData) && (
              <div css={{ display: 'none', '@media print': { display: 'block' } }}>
                {!coversheetData.verificationFailures.length ? (
                  <CoversheetPrint {...coversheetData} />
                ) : (
                  <VerificationErrorCoversheet {...coversheetData} />
                )}
              </div>
            )}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I had to do the opposite of this in all other divs

In other divs I did:

2. window.print() all together didn't seem to work on localhost